# React native navigation error- navigating issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to create react native application.But it is throwing error. I used react-native-navigation. 
(I am trying to create react native application.But it is throwing error. I used react-native-navigation. )

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import DashboardScreen from "./src/component/Dashboard";
import LoginScreen from "./src/component/Auth/Login";
import RegisterScreen from "./src/component/Auth/Register";

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Dashboard: DashboardScreen });
const AuthStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  SignIn: LoginScreen,
  Register: RegisterScreen
});

export const RootNaviation = () => {
  return createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
      {
        Auth: AuthStack,
        App: AppStack
      },
      { initialRouteName: "Auth" }
    )
  );
};
```

App File

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";
import { SwitchNavigator } from "./Router";
const Nav = SwitchNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="dafdlka" />
      <Nav />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLtrR.jpg)

Comment: what is the error, please post

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLtrR.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have never created a variable called `SwitchNavigator`.

You can use `RootNaviation`

```js
import { RootNaviation } from "./Router"
...
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="dafdlka" />
      <RootNaviation />
    </View>
  );
}
```